# Is there any trivial ring which isn't null?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

By a trivial ring, I mean one that fulfills the following: ${\forall}x,y\,{\in}\,R:xy=0_R$

A null ring is a ring with only one element.

So far I couldn't think of any trivial ring which isn't null. Any examples?

Comment: A fun fact about rings without unity: there are abelian groups which are not the underlying group of any ring with unity, but (by Arnaud D.'s answer) *every* abelian group is the underlying group of a ring without unity. For example, take the abelian group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ - it's a good exercise to show that this cannot be made into a ring with unity.

Comment: Noah's good exercise has been asked on this site : see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262462/show-that-is-not-possible-to-form-a-unity-ring-structure-on-q-z#2262473

Answer (score 9):

If you require your ring to have an identity $1_R$ then any trivial ring has to be null, since$$a=1_R\cdot a=0_R$$for all $a\in R$.

If you don't require your ring to have an identity, then any abelian group can be endowed with a trivial product.

Comment: Wouldn't the ring in your first example have two elements, $1$ and $0$?

Comment: They would be equal : just take $a=1_R$ in my equation to see this.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the following sub-ring  $\{\bar 0,\bar 2\}\subset\mathbb Z_4$ would do the trick

Comment: Is it really a ring? $2$ doesn't have an inverse under addition here.

Comment: It is its own inverse.

Comment: actually $\bar{-2}=\bar{2}$ in $\mathbb Z_4$

Comment: @user285146:  If I understand the example, this is a ring without unity.  $\overline{2} + \overline{2} = \overline{0}$ is the additive identity.

Comment: Relating this to Arnaud D.'s answer: note that this is just the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ endowed with the trivial multiplication map $x\cdot y=0$.

Comment: What does the bar over a number mean?

Comment: @user285146 It stands for "the equivalence class of" - this is often omitted, but is technically necessary if $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ is to be a set of equivalence classes of integers as opposed to a set of *certain representatives of* those equivalence classes.

Answer (score 2):

$(\{0,a\},+,\cdot)$ with $a+a:=0$ and $a\cdot a:=0$ is a [rng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29), i.e. a ring without $1$. It is structurally equivalent to the $\{[0],[2]\}$ subring of $\mathbb Z_4$ [user307935](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/307935/user307935) suggested.

If, on the other hand, you require an $1$ element then you can satisfy $1\cdot 1=1$ (from the ring axioms) and $1\cdot 1=0$ (from your constraint) only by $1=0$, so you'd be back to the null ring.